# Maximum determinant of a $m\times m$ - matrix with entries $1..n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, determinant

I want to find the maximal possible determinant of a $ m\times m$ - matrix A with
 entries $1..n$.

Conjecture 1 : The maximum possible determinant can be achieved by a matrix 
                only conatining 1 and n.

Conjecture 2 : If A contains only 1 and n, then it can be writte in the form
                $$A~=~(n-1)H~+~\pmatrix{1..1\\.\ \ \ .\\.\ \ \ .\\1..1}$$
                where H is a binary matrix.
                Sylvester's theorem gives 
                $$det(A) = (n-1)^{m-1}(det(H)(n-1)+S)$$
                where S is the sum of the entries of $det(H)\ H^{-1}$.
                For $m \le 20$, the maximum determinant of H is known, but
                unfortunately det(A) also depends on S. My conjecture is
                that the maximum possible S can be reached by a matrix H
                with maximum determinant.

- Can these conjectures be proved ?
- What is the largest possible value for S, given H has maximum determinant D ?

Comment: For m=2, I get D = 1 and S = 2 as optimal values and $\pmatrix {1&0 \\ 0&1}$ is a matrix H with these values.

Comment: For m = 3, I get D = 2 and S = 3 as optimal values and $\pmatrix {0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0}$ is one of three matrices with these values.

Comment: For m = 3, D = 3 and S = 5 seem to be optimal and $\pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&0&1&1\\1&1&0&1\\0&1&1&0}$ is a matrix with these values.

Comment: For m = 4, D = 5 and S = 9 seem to be optimal and $\pmatrix{0&1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1&0}$ is a matrix with these values.

Comment: For m = 5 , the best I achieved is D = 9 and S = 17 with the matrix $\pmatrix {0&0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&1&1&0&1\\1&0&0&1&1&1\\0&1&0&1&1&0\\0&1&0&0&1&1\\1&1&1&0&0&0}$

Comment: This is essentially the same question as maximizing the determinant of a 0-1 matrix, or a $\pm1$ matrix. There's a conjecture that the Hadamard bound can always be achieved if $m$ is a multiple of 4.

Comment: The matrix $\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&1&1\\1&1&0&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1&0&1}$ improves the case m = 5, giving D = 9 and S = 18. So, it has the same (maximum possible) determinant but gives higher values for the corresponding matrix containing 1 and n.

Comment: So, the problem of maximizing the determinant of $(1,n)-$ matrices is more difficult than maximizing the determinant of $(0,1)-$ matrices.

Comment: I noticed that in the third example, m = 4, would be correct, similar for the following examples. How can I fix these typos without having to input the matrices again ? Alas, it is not possible to edit a post after 5 minutes. However, D ans S and the matrices are correct.

Comment: I just found out that conjecture 1 is true. If a matrix has an entry neither 1 nor n, replacing this element by 1 or n, depending on the sign of the adjoint corresponding to this element, either increases the determinant or let it unchanged. This can be repeated until all entries are either 1 or n.